# Importing a report from Oracle Reports Builder into SQL Developer

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oraclereports

I'm trying to migrate a bunch of legacy reports (currently maintained with Oracle Reports Builder 11) into SQL Developer -- either as individual database packages or as "User-Defined Reports".

I have figured out how to save the report as either .xml or .jsp from Reports Builder, but importing the file into SQL Developer just chokes.  Here are some of the errors I get when trying to run the imported report:

```
oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayPanel:May 11, 2016 3:13:43 PM oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayPanel refresh
INFO: DisplayPanel.Refresh(true}

Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
  o.dbtools.raptor.query.QueryUtils.getQuery(QueryUtils.java:208)
  o.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayModel.getQuery(DisplayModel.java:389)
  o.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayModel.getQuery(DisplayModel.java:385)
  o.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayPanel.refresh(DisplayPanel.java:555)
  o.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayPanel$12.run(DisplayPanel.java:479)
  j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

SQL Developer is installed on the same VM where the Oracle Database resides.

**My question:** Is this import even feasible?  Or are .xml files derived from .rdf files incompatible with the User-Defined Reports feature in SQL Developer?  If so, would it be possible to automatically create an Oracle package from the contents of this file, so that I can try running the logic of this report in a different way?  I don't care so much about the existing formatting or visual elements of the report, just the inbuilt functions.

Here's a part of the header from the xml (generated from the original .rdf), in case it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<report name="rpt1220" DTDVersion="9.0.2.0.10"
 afterParameterFormTrigger="afterpform" beforeReportTrigger="beforereport">
  <xmlSettings xmlTag="ACFP1220" xmlPrologType="text">
  <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>]]>
  </xmlSettings>
  <comment>
  <![CDATA[NAME:                     rpt1220.rdf
```